# Python clean code: which should I do? pass parameters vs use properties vs modify in place

Tags: python

Let me clarify my question. I've found myself not know what to choose in the following scenarios

**Scenario 1 - Function that modifies an array (or other mutable object)**

Option 1: Modify array in function and return it.

```
def double(arr):
    arr = 2*arr
    return arr

def main:
    # do stuff
    arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])
    arr = double(arr)
    # do more stuff
```

Option 2: Modify array in place

```
def double(arr):
    arr = 2*arr

def main:
    # do stuff
    arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])
    double(arr)
    # do more stuff
```

**Scenario 2 - Class method which uses class property**

Option 1: Pass class property as parameter

```
class Class():
    def __init__(property):
        self.property = property

    def main():
        result = calculate(self.property)
        return result

    def calculate(property):
        # do stuff with property
        return result
```

Option 2: Just reference the property directly

```
class Class():
    def __init__(property):
        self.property = property

    def main():
        result = calculate()
        return result

    def calculate():
        # do stuff with self.property
        return result
```

I can think of some cases where the choice is clear but just wondering if there are some rules of thumb or common practices.

I would like to get answers with reputable references if possible as I know this type of topic can be very opinion driven.

Comment: I think you swapped the code of `double` for Scenario 1 options 1 and 2

Comment: Scenario 1: Nothing is performed in-place here. In the Python builtins and stdlib functions usually return a copy and methods return an in-place modified version, e.g. compare `sorted` and `list.sort`. Scenario 2: it depends if `calculate` works on the class state not. It can be `staticmethod` if not, otherwise it should use `self`.

Comment: Have you tried the example codes? They don't work.

Comment: `result` is also a local name; as soon as `main()` exits, the name is gone. It's not available to `Class.calculate`.

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: @CorentinPane sorted

Comment: @Asocia I didn't test them. I'm not checking to see if the code will work or not. It's more of a best practices question. Anyway I made one thing clearer by using a numpy array instead

Comment: @chepner just added a return to sort that out. But for clarity, I'm aware of that distinction between a local variable and a class property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Scenario 1

When you pass in a variable in python, reassigning the value of a passed variable (not to be confused with modifying the value IN a passed variable), does not modify that variable in-place (see [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)).

So the below won't actually modify mylist outside the scope of the function:

```
def double_list(mylist):
    mylist = 2 * mylist
```

But this will (again see the post I linked for a better explanation):

```
def add_to_list(mylist):
    mylist.append(0)
```

So for scenario 1, option 2 won't actually do anything so stick with option 1.

---

## Scenario 2

You forgot to add `self` as the first parameter to all the class function. Unless any of the functions are intended to be `@classmethod`s or `@staticmethod`s your probably better off just sticking with option 2 and use the properties directly:

```
class Class:
    def __init__(self, property):
        self.property = property

    def main(self):
        result = self.calculate()
        return result

    def calculate(self):
        # do stuff with self.property
        return result
```

Your use of main here however is not usual. Main shouldn't be part of a Class. Why not just call `Class.calculate()` directly? All main does in this scenario is return the same thing as calculate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. regarding self and main that was just me hastily writing pseudocode. Regarding the in place editing that won't work, thanks I didn't notice that. I must have been doing it when I was woking with a function in the same scope as the call...? Anyway point taken